# Buffon's needle problem: Compute how many times we must toss the needle in order to be at least 95% certain to be...

Tags: probability

I'm stuck at this exercise about Buffons needle problem from my book "Probability, Statistics, and Stochastic Processes" by Peter Olofsson and Mikael Andersson.

The excersise goes:
"Consider the Buffon's needle problem. Use the delta method to compute how many times we must toss the needle in order to be at least $95$% certain to be $-0.01$ to $+0.01$ of $π$"

I don't know how to start, and don't know how to do the calculations.

Is there maybe someone who could help get me started or show me the calculation?

(Math is not my major, so I'm sorry if I need it cut into very small pieces)

Comment: Did youknow  what Buffon's Needle problem is or what the delta method is (if not, check wikipedia)? What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: I know what Buffon's Needle problem is, and know what the delta method is, but not how to actually use it, so guess I'm stuck at that point.